How to setup routing between subnets? No vlans
I have one physical network 172.16.28.0
and I want to devide the network using different mask (no vlan), Also, I have 172.16.28.1 gateway that I need all subnets to have access to. I don't have l3 switches.How do you make PCs in subnets see 172.16.28.1 gateway
Upd. I don't have permission to configure the 172.16.28.1 gateway

Normally, you would assign the router an address from each subnet. For example, if you divide a /24 into four /26's (and decide to use all four of them), then the router would have four different IP addresses, one within each of those /26's – the computers within 172.16.28.64/26 wouldn't be using 172.16.28.1; they would be using 172.16.28.65 or something such.
This works the same way whether you use VLANs or physical LANs – or even if you just put multiple subnets on the same ethernet without any L2 isolation. (Though in the latter case, you could get away with only a single IP address on the gateway, but it's best not to do that, and to just treat it as four isolated networks.)
"L3 switches" are not needed. They're more-or-less just a high-performance combination of a router and a regular L2 switch, so you can achieve the same thing with a separate router and separate L2 switches. (In particular, "L3 switches" are not needed for VLANs – that's 100% a L2 feature; if your L2 switches support 802.1Q VLANs then you can have VLANs.)

Upd. I don't have permission to configure the 172.16.28.1 gateway

Then you cannot really divide the network in any useful way. You could try changing your devices' subnet masks, in hope that the gateway won't forward packets back into the same network, but I don't think that's something to rely on.
Most likely, with its current configuration it would just forward any traffic between the "subnets" without restriction (as it thinks it is only reflecting packets back to the same large subnet, from its point of view), so there would be no isolation at IP level – and since you don't have VLANs (thus no L2 isolation either), the result is that your changes in subnet masks would achieve exactly nothing.
But if you really need to isolate groups of devices from each other, then you might need to set up your own additional router, configure it with completely separate network numbers (i.e. unrelated to 172.16.28.0), and enable NAT (masquerading) so that it all appears as a single 172.16.28.x device to the larger network; similar to how 'wireless routers' work at home.
Even just getting multiple such generic 'wireless routers' – with one group of devices each – would give you separate, fully isolated subnets on the cheap. (It won't be tidy, and the administrators of the broader network probably won't appreciate it, but they also probably won't notice it.)

Thank you for answering! "..your changes in subnet masks would achieve exactly nothing" Thats exactly what happened when i changed pc's subnet to /26. i could reach any devices on the network.  I've read post multiple times, but im too stupid to understand, do you suggest to get each subnet a router, put them behind NAT (172.16.28.1 would be the gateway on the router), if i do that does that mean if i want to reach some devices in different subnet i need to create static routes on the routers? And am i correct that you cant isolate subnets without routers or vlans capable switches?

Also, what if i had the internet access gateway on that same network does that mean i get double NAT'ed ?

It depends on what kind of router you get... With typical home-use "wireless routers" your only choice would be to add a 2nd layer of NAT, yes – and static routes between them. Works out-of-the-box but messy and not very flexible at all. On the other hand, with something like a Mikrotik hEX (or similar), you can handle all 4 subnets with just a single router, and you have an additional option of Proxy-ARP instead of 2nd NAT – far more flexible, but at the cost of requiring some manual setup. (Still personally I'd suggest trying the latter first, as the cost of a hEX isn't that much.)
